# Accessing Route data in root component, route data is empty

Tags: angular, angular-router

My problem is that I have a `lang.component` loaded with `<router-outlet>`. What I need is to access ActivatedRoute params in the root component which is `app.component` but all route data there is empty. I am able to access route data from `lang.component` normally by subscribing to params link to code that you can run: https://plnkr.co/edit/gTXPUb6TvatbMyOPPRKj

If you run the code and open your console you can see two logs. It shows you what the problem is.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Same here, any news?

Comment: @siebmanb Look at the answer.

Comment: This is not an answer in my case, I need to access the route data, not params. The data is added in the RouterConfig.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57447329/5366641

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using ActivatedRoute use Router.

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        var snapshot = this.router.routerState.firstChild(this.route).snapshot;

        var params = snapshot.params;
    }
})
```

Comment: Didn't know you couldn't use ActivatedRoute to access child route params from a parent route. thanks!